# My code for inserting numbers to the start of linked list doesn't compile

Tags: c, linked-list, cs50

here's the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}node;

node* head;// global variable can be accessed anywhere

void Insert(int x);//function to insert the number in start
void print();//function to print them

int main()
{
    head = NULL;// empty list

    printf("How many numbers?\n");
    int n,i,x;
    scanf("%i", &n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the Number\n");
        scanf("%i", &x);
        Insert(x);
    }
    print();
}

void Insert(int x)
{
    node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void print()
{
    node* temp = head;

    print("List is: ");

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

so I tried to compile the code in VS Code & it asks for the How many numbers, then asks for to enter the number & after entering the 1st number, the program stops.
so I tried to compile in CS50 ide & this is the error I got-

```
linkedlist1.c:41:1: error: all paths through this function will call itself [-Werror,-Winfinite-recursion]
{
^
```

Line 41 is 1st curly bracket of the function `void print()`

why is this happening? & how should I solve it?

Comment: I guess you have `print("List is: ");` wrong. That will trigger infinite recursion. It should be `printf("List is: ");` no ?

Comment: One tip: use function prototypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling

```
print("List is: ");
```

inside the function

```
void print()
```

unconditionally is an infinite recursion.

You may meant

```
printf("List is: ");
```

(call `printf` with `f`, not `print`)

To avoid this kind of error, you should mark functions that doesn't take arguments not to take arguments explicitly. This can be done by using `void` as the arguments like

```
void print(void)
```